# No se me ejecuta metodo messaging.onMessage(){ ... }

Tags: javascript, firebase

Buenos días compañeros,

Llevo días con un problema de notificaciones y no encuentro el motivo. Soy bastante nuevo en esto. Quiero implementar las notificaciones push en la web. He buscado algunos ejemplos y he conseguido recibir notif. cuando la web está en segundo plano. Pero cuando tiene el foco, no hay manera de recibirlas. Debugando, veo que no se me ejecuta el metodo: **messaging.onMessage(function(notification){ ... }** que por lo que he leído, es el encargado de ejecutar la notif. "manualmente".

En el html, dentro las etiquetes body tengo:

```
<body>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

  <script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "https://...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background messages.
  var messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
    console.log('granted()');
    return messaging.getToken();

  }).then(function(token) {
    if(token) {
      console.log('token= '+token);                   
    } else {
      console.log('anularToken()');
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('denied()');
  });


  // Si rebo Notif...
  messaging.onMessage(function(notification) {
    console.log("notification= "+notification);
    console.log("title= "+notification.title);
    console.log("body= "+notification.body);
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Por otro lado, tengo estos 2 ficheros en la raiz del dominio.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
}
```

Y **firebase-messaging-sw.js**:

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': "...",
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Tambien deciros que el dominio es "https://". Y lo dicho, cuando la web no tiene el foco recibo las Notificaciones correctamente (se me muestra notif. en la parte inferior derecha de la pantalla), pero cuando estoy trabajando en la web no recibo nada (no se me ejecuta el onMessage(), no me aparecen los logs en la console del navegador).

Desde ya muchas gracias!